# How should I remove all dicts from a list that have None as one of their values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list like so:

```
[{'name': 'Blah1', 'age': x}, {'name': 'Blah2', 'age': y}, {'name': None, 'age': None}]
```

It is guaranteed that both 'name' and 'age' values will either be filled or empty.

I tried this:

```
for person_dict in list:
    if person_dict['name'] == None:
        list.remove(person_dict)
```

But obviously that does not work because the for loop skips over an index sometimes and ignores some blank people.

I am relatively new to Python, and I am wondering if there is a list method that can target dicts with a certain value associated with a key.

EDIT: Fixed tuple notation to list as comments pointed out

Comment: That is a tuple of dicts, not a list

Comment: BTW: you have tuple () not list [] - you couldn't remove element.

Comment: Oh whoops. I actually have a list. Wrong notation, will fix.

Comment: your function is working fine . if it is list

Comment: @ sundar nataraj Сундар - try with `[{'name': None, 'age': None},{'name': None, 'age': None},{'name': 'Blah1', 'age': 'x'}]` and you get wrong result.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Yep. When it removes an entry, it goes to the next index, which actually causes it to step over one. Or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test for the presence of `None` in the dict's values to test ALL dict keys for the `None` value:

```
>>> ToD=({'name': 'Blah1', 'age': 'x'}, {'name': 'Blah2', 'age': 'y'}, {'name': None, 'age': None})
>>> [e for e in ToD if None not in e.values()]
[{'age': 'x', 'name': 'Blah1'}, {'age': 'y', 'name': 'Blah2'}]
```

Or, use filter:

```
>>> filter(lambda d: None not in d.values(), ToD)
({'age': 'x', 'name': 'Blah1'}, {'age': 'y', 'name': 'Blah2'})
```

Or, if it is a limited test to 'name':

```
>>> filter(lambda d: d['name'], ToD)
({'age': 'x', 'name': 'Blah1'}, {'age': 'y', 'name': 'Blah2'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension as a filter like this

```
[c_dict for c_dict in dict_lst if all(c_dict[key] is not None for key in c_dict)]
```

This will make sure that you get only the dictionaries where all the values are not `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index,person_dict in enumerate(lis):
    if person_dict['name'] == None:
        del lis[index]
```

you can also try

```
lis=[person_dict  for person_dict in lis if person_dict['name'] != None]
```

never use `List` as variable

Answer (score 0):

You can create new list with accepted data. If you have tuple then you have to create new list.

List comprehension could be faster but this version is more readable for beginners.

```
data = ({'name': 'Blah1', 'age': 'x'}, {'name': 'Blah2', 'age': 'y'}, {'name': None, 'age': None})

new_data = []

for x in data:
    if x['name']: # if x['name'] is not None and x['name'] != ''
        new_data.append(x)

print new_data
```